# how can i display image from my database

Tags: php, image

This is another bunch of code I tried:

form.html

```
<form method='post' action='upload2.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Select file :<input type='file' name='filename' size='10' />
<input type='submit' value='upload'>
```

upload.php

```
  <?include "connect.php";
   $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
   $image = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];

   $sql = "INSERT INTO files ". "VALUES ('', '$name', '$image')";

   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());?>
```

display.php

```
 <?php
  include "connect.php";
  $fid = $_FILES['fid'];

  // do some validation here to ensure id is safe
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE fid='$fid'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $image = $row['content'];

  echo $image;?>
```

Here page I call that display.php to view the file:

```
  <?
  echo "<img src=display.php?fid=1  />";
  ?>
```

It just show blank page

owh before I forget.. this my table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `files` ( `fid` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY COMMENT
 'unique id', `name` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL COMMENT 'file name', `content` BLOB NOT
  NULL COMMENT 'actual file' ) ENGINE = MYISAM COMMENT = 'Uploaded files'
```

This time just a blank page
the image is successful save inside database but I can't display it back in page. what my mistake... I already view through here the solution but still I can't make it work.. it either won't display anything or it show broken image

Comment: u need to move the file outside the tempfolder, see [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). Images that are uploaded and are not moved outside the temp folder will be deleted after script execution

Comment: First you need to know that MYSQL* extention is already removed in the current php versions and will not work in the future. The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.

Comment: Instead of saving file in DB you have to save your file in a directory, because when there is lot of images in DB then it becomes heavy, then you will face the slow processing problems, so first of all create a folder in directory where you creates the php upload file, then use move_uploaded_file function, and then in this function you have to provide image temp name and the location of the which you create.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to move image file from temp folder to your main images directory and than serve it from there.

A complete example can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: While the link can answer OP's question its better not to answer with just a mere link as they can dissapear over time. Beter to provide example code here

Comment: Got it, I thought that would be too much of code, but anyway will keep that in mind for future, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the image into mysql database

```
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']));
$sql = "INSERT INTO files ". "VALUES ('', '$name', '$image')";
```

Fetch image from table and embed in the page using `<img src>`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE fid='$fid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$image = $row['content'];

echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $image ).'"/>';
```

PS. Usage of mysql_* functions not recommeded. Instead you can use mysqli_* or pdo_* functions.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for help... now i understand what my mistake.. the problem is that my file is not transfer to the.. @madforstrength thanks for the link
[the tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

1st the form.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>

  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Select image to upload:
   <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
   </form>

   </body>
   </html>
```

and the the upload script

```
 <?php
 $target_dir = "uploads/";
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been
uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}?>
```

this code i provide the folder that being set will save the file into

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
```

now just try to apply database information in several part
to display the file need to write, 
    something close to this

thanks everyone